# Amadeus Self-API Returning Currency in Euros

Tags: amadeus

I managed to set up an API on my website to pull up flight data, but no matter where I search, whether it's from Canada to Canada or Canada to the United Kingdom, or United States to the United Kingdom, the response is always coming up in Euros. Is there a means to change the response to display in USD or Canadian Dollars?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for information on creating a minimal reproducible example so it's easier for others to help.

Comment: I'm not really sure which file I need to post. I've got like four different files and a .js file, but I don't know which of those would link to the API